# Netbeans build.xml to execute when using Ant

Tags: ant, build, execute, build.xml

I'm relatively new to using build files and Ant to compile and execute from a command line so i wanted to know how it would be possible to modify the build-impl.xml file auto generated from netbeans so that after it compiles it also executes the program.

Currently when i type just "ant" in the command window where the build.xml file is listed it compiles and etc but then says

```
-do-jar-copylibs:
 [copylibs] Nothing to copy.
     [echo] To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
     [echo] java -jar "C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Word Documents\Java Test Code\NetbeansVersion\Cops\dist\Cops.jar"
```

I can run that command and it will run fine, but i want the program to execute by just typing ant.

The build.xml file - [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5vyA6hiJ)

Build-impl.xml file - [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HRdPKNC4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple "tasks" available in ant that you could use to accomplish this.

You can use either of these:
[Java Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html),
[Exec Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

Those documentation pages provide examples as well.  Before you go there though, you might want to start at the [basic manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/) to get an idea of the structure of an ant build file to determine where and how you want to add this execution step in.

It feels a little "off" to me to have your build script executing the program, but I'm sure you've got a reason, so I might suggest adding a new target that does the build steps and then also runs this command to kick off the program.  That way you've still got the option of running the build without running the program.